# Is there a way to edit a specific message using the message id. Discord.PY

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there a way to edit a message a discord bot user has previously send by using a message id?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit a message in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711572/how-to-edit-a-message-in-discord-py)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553424/how-to-make-a-bot-edit-its-own-message-in-discord-py

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the function `await message.edit()`

There's more options to edit the message, like `on_raw_message_edit`

check the discord.py documentation for more information, it's all there [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I should have really read the comments on my question